# Taking screenshot on Pi 5 desktop?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bookworm, pi-5

Built-in `scrot` creates a PNG that, while sized right, is entirely black.

[raspi2png](https://github.com/AndrewFromMelbourne/raspi2png) builds successfully (using `libpng-dev` instead of `libpng12-dev` as its build script specifies) but running it errors-out with:

```
* failed to open vchiq instance
```

`/dev/vchiq` doesn't seem to exist anymore.

I'm not knowing enough of Wayland vs. Xorg vs. RandR vs. whatever-changed-to-support-Vulkan etc.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Bookworm does not use X so `scrot` won't work. I am surprised it doesn't generate an error indicating it can't open X display.

Comment: Thanks Milliways, good for me to know on X!  Unfortunately now I'm questioning my sanity, because although I definitely have a black-pixel-filled file named `2023-10-30-134334_1920x1080_scrot.png` in my `~` (name cut-n-pasted), now that I run `scrot` or `sudo scrot` again, I see this: `Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified`...`scrot: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah? [:0]`  Which I swear it wasn't displaying before! That stylized message I would've remembered. Though I've done plenty other fiddling since & can no longer "scroll up" in my xterm far enough.

Comment: Try: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Screen_capture#Wayland

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to successfully take a screenshot from CLI using `grim`; it saved to ~/Pictures

Comment: Perfect.  Me too!  Just what I was looking for.  Thanks morissette and goldilocks!